# Passar um array para uma controller webapi

Tags: c#, react, asp.net-web-api, axios

Estou com dificuldades em passar um array para uma controller via Axios.

Exemplo do código WEBAPI Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("openshape")]
    [Route("api/shape/openshape")]
    public IEnumerable<Fields> OpenShape(FileOpen[] path)
```

Quando eu mando a requisição no React ela chega `null` na WEBAPI.

Exemplo do método no React:

```
var  path = []; 
var ListSelect = Object.assign([], e.target.files); 


for(var i = 0; i < ListSelect.length; i++){
  let result = { data:'', fileName:''}
  var reader = new FileReader(); 
  reader.readAsDataURL(ListSelect[i]); 
  reader.onload = e => { 
    result.data = e.target.result.toString();  
  }
    
  result.fileName = ListSelect[i].name; 

  path.push(result); 
}

let obj = await api.get("/shape/openshape/", {params: {path: path}})
```

Exemplo da classe FileOpen:

```
public class FileOpen
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A requisição que está tentando realizar é um `GET` e requisições `GET` semanticamente não possuem body, ou seja, não recebem objetos complexos no corpo da requisição.

O que você pode fazer é alterar o método para `POST` ou `PUT` para resolver o problema, porém existe uma questão que deve ser avaliada que é o contexto da requisição se ela é uma requisição que vai enviar dados os métodos `POST` e `PUT` resolvem, porém se é uma requisição que busca informações, deve se avaliar outras alternativas:

Receber no Controller um parâmetro via `QueryString` e convertendo a String para um array. Ou seja, ao invés de mandar o objeto no data da requisição, vc mandaria um JSON como string via parâmetro da requisição, receberia este JSON no Controller e converteria este JSON em um array de objetos. Abaixo um exemplo:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [ActionName("openshape")]
 [Route("api/shape/openshape")]
 public IEnumerable<Fields> OpenShape([FromUri] string path) {
   FileOpen[] paths = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileOpen[]>(path);
 }
```

No React:

```
var  path = []; 
var ListSelect = Object.assign([], e.target.files); 

for(var i = 0; i < ListSelect.length; i++){
  let result = { data:'', fileName:''}
  var reader = new FileReader(); 
  reader.readAsDataURL(ListSelect[i]); 
  reader.onload = e => { 
    result.data = e.target.result.toString();  
  }
    
  result.fileName = ListSelect[i].name; 

  path.push(result); 
}

let pathStr = JSON.stringify(path);

let obj = await api.get("/shape/openshape/", {params: {path: pathStr}})
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém agora o erro fica na conversão do array para JSON. 
O Valor do result.data está retornando nulo.

Comment: o problema pode ser por culpa da identação do conteudo do Json, dê uma olhada na documentação em https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm

Comment: Consegui arrumar. 
O problema estava na hora da leitura do reader.onload, pois ele carrega os dados mas depois que eu adiciono ele na lista os valores desaparece magicamente kkkkk 

então eu mudei a estrutura, deixando o usuário fazer o upload dos dois arquivos manualmente um de cada vez.